# Azure SQL Update Performance Indexed

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

On Azure SQL Database:

```
UPDATE SomeLargeTable 
SET [nonPKbutIndexedColumn] = newValue 
WHERE [nonPKbutIndexedColumn] = value;
    


UPDATE SomeLargeTable 
SET [nonPKbutIndexedColumn] = newValue 
WHERE [PKcolumn] IN (SELECT [PKcolumn] FROM SomeLargeTable 
                     WHERE [nonPKbutIndexedColumn] = value);
```

What about the performance of these queries? Other suggestions also are welcome...

Comment: Post query execution plans, it'll reveal the truth ; )

Comment: second query for sure is not performant and actually doesn't make sense. as far as you have index on that column you are ok

Answer (score 0):

The performance of any Data Manipulation Language (DML) command depends on many factors like volume of data in the tables, how efficiently the schema is designed, etc.

As long as your tables are properly indexed, both queries will run fine. There shouldn't be any performance issue. You can check the time taken for the query at the bottom of Query Editor in Azure SQL Database.

Additionally, you can use [Query Performance Insight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/query-performance-insight-use) in Azure SQL Database which provides intelligent query analysis for single and pooled databases. It helps identify the top resource consuming and long-running queries in your workload. This helps you find the queries to optimize to improve overall workload performance and efficiently use the resource.